# How to find duplicate names within two large files?

Tags: python, parsing

I have two CSVs. 
One is a file of names. (~1000 lines)
The other is a tab delimited with various information on different people, wherein column 7 their names are held. (~2000000 lines)

I want to find duplicate names between these files.

As of now, I'm inputting the names from the first file into a list, and then checking line by line in the other file to see if the line's name matches any in the list. If so, I output that as a duplicate. I know it's not optimal to read line by line 2 million lines, so I'm wondering if you guys would do something different.

```
newList = []
otherList = []

with open('listofnames.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        newList.append(line)

for x in files:
    with open('%s' % x) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            y = (((line.strip('\n')).split(','))[7]
            if y in newList:
                print(y)
```

It only printed out one duplicate name 32 times.

Comment: I don't really know Python, so won't create an answer, but a set is a perfect solution for this type of problem. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: can you show a sample of the csv files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a large file line by line is not a problem. Decent Python implementations (among them the standard CPython) provide buffering on file io, so it takes the same time to read by large chunks or line by line because internally the accesses are chunked.

What is problematic is to search many times (one per line) a word in a rather large list, because searches in a list are sequential so you will will have 1000 comparisons if the name is not found and a mean 500 comparisons when it is. It would be much more efficient to use a `set` because a set is hashed which allow direct accesses (O(1) instead of O(n))

So my advice is to slightly change your code to:

```
import csv

newlist = set()
otherList = []

with open('listofnames.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        newList.add(line.strip())

for x in files:
    with open(x) as f:           # no need to format: use directly the filename
        rd = csv.reader(f)       # but rely on a csv.reader to parse a csv file
        next(rd)                 # skip the header line
        for row in rd:
            y = row[7]           # process the right field
            if y in newList:     # searching in a set is fast
                print(y)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! Set helped tremendously as well as using CSV reader. Really really helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use other package, I suggest you to use pandas package.

Firstly you open your files with **_pd.read_csv('your_file_name')**.
Secondely use **merge()** function

```py
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.read_csv('your_file_name')
df2 = pd.read_csv('your_file_name2')

df1.merge(df2)
```

Exemple :

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Name': ['name2', 'name3', 'name4',  'name7', 'name8', 'name9']})

In [1] : df1.merge(df2)
Out[2] :    
Name
-------
0   name2
1   name3
2   name4
```

Comment: Using a dataframe did help! Found that just using CSV reader within the python script worked the same wonders. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Serges answer, consider using pandas' read_csv function. This is generally faster than manual parsing and saves you from doing manual stripping operations which are prone to cause errors

`(((line.strip('\n')).split(','))[7]`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Here is some example code. You just need to replace the filename and column name of your large csv:

```
import pandas as pd
names = set(pd.read_csv('listofnames.csv').values)
big_file = pd.read_csv('big_file.csv')
duplicates = set(big_file[big_file['column_name_of_column_7'].isin(names)]['column_name_of_column_7'].values)
```

Comment: *This is generally faster than manual parsing*. Have you any evidence of that? In my tests, reading a csv with the csv module is 4 times faster that with pandas. No surprise, because pandas does much more job, which is useless here.

Comment: I would not consider using the csv module as manual parsing ;). Manual parsing is something like using the ```line.strip()``` function. As to whether the csv module or pandas is faster, I'll do some profiling and post the results here.